# apache httpd mod_tile error: "Failed to create shared memory segment on file"

Tags: apache, centos, mod-tile

This question may seem out of place, but it appears it's coming from mod_tile, so thought I'd give it a shot here.. (I also haven't managed to get answers elsewhere..)
Started getting this error once a week during logrotate, when it was attempting to reload apache httpd server:

`[Sun Jul 23 03:27:25.301291 2017] [tile:error] [pid 19728:tid 140568496863200] (17)File exists: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /tmp/httpd_shm.19728`

Tried switching to stop, sleep 10, start -- does not help.
Running apache httpd 2.4.6 on centos 6 ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit here, but wonder if the problem is the same one as https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/issues/166 ?  Not explicitly related to Docker, obviously, but could the same PID is assigned to httpd at restart?  You've already tried stopping and waiting before restarting so it's difficult to suggest what else to do in that area.

Comment: This issue occurs on reload as well where the process id is supposed to be the same and it is not killed, so I don't see how this is related..

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old but I ran into the same problem. The solution for me was to mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs` file system, which gets properly cleaned up on every docker restart.

Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/